# Gradle library not found in a multimodule

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I try to create a lib with many spring element (entity, repository) and that library will be used by other spring boot application

in my git folder i have 3 folder

- intranet
- extranet
- common

my build.gradle for common

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.3' apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.acme.lib.common'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}


compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

the **settings.gradle** of common

```
rootProject.name = 'acme-common'
```

When i build it, I see a jar file in build/libs

In the build.gradle on my my intranet project

```
implementation project(':common')
```

When i build i get error about this line

```
implementation project(':common')
```

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'intranet'.

> Project with path ':common' could not be found in root project 'intranet'.

**settings.gradle** of the root

```
rootProject.name='acme'
include 'common', 'extranet', 'intranet'
```

**build.gradle** project of the root

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: "java"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the contents of your root `settings.gradle` file.

Comment: information provided

Comment: How many `settings.gradle` files do you have? Unless you are using [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/composite_builds.html), there should only be one. What is the output of `./gradlew projects -q`?